# Vim no me toma el color scheme instalado con Plug

Tags: vim

estoy tratando de configurar vim, ya tengo mi _vimrc configurado, en teoria ya tengo funcionando Plug para instalar cosas, ya que me clono el repositorio y realizo el proceso de instalacion del "Tema" , los archivos estan en donde se supone es la ruta correcta, pero el colorscheme no me lo toma con el nombre indicado, aqui les dejo mi vimrc y tambien en donde esta localizado mi theme, espero alguien sepa que esta pasando, mil gracias

_vimrc

set number
syntax enable

call plug#begin('~/vimfiles/plugged')

Plug 'morhetz/gruvbox'

call plug#end()

colorscheme gruvbox

la ruta de la carpeta gruvbox es C:\Users\Naz\vimfiles\plugged

mi _vimrc esta en C:\Users\Naz

Cabe mencionar que los ajustes que hago en el vimrc si se aplican pero no el color scheme

Comment: Prueba esto
let g:gruvbox_bold='1'
let g:gruvbox_termcolors='256'
let gruvbox_contrast_dark='hard'
colorscheme gruvbox
sobre todo el modo de color 256

Answer (score 0):

Antes de nada deberías asegurarte que tu terminal está configurado para 256 colores, para eso ingresa en el terminal de tu equipo el siguiente comando.

```
    echo $TERM
```

si te devuelve "xterm-256color", el problema es de configuración del plugin que seguramente no esté correcta, para lo cual deberías ir a su página de github "https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox" y ver opciones de instalación y configuración.